# Background-image на background-color

Tags: html, css, background

Помогите сделать картинку `opacity 0.6` чтобы на фоне `background-color` был виден
Вот пример что мне нужно сделать

[image: Пример]

Html

```
<section class="banner">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="item">
       <h1>We’re an Independent Design and <span>Development</span> Agency</h1>
     </div>
    </div>  
</section>
```

Css

```
.banner{
   background: rgba(0,0,0, 0.6) url("../images/banner.jpg") no-repeat;
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяй их местами и замени фон на другой background:

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.6), rgba(0,0,0,.6)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLtG.jpg);
  font-size: 6em;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>Just a text</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо вам большое очень помогли )))

Answer (score 3):

Наложите затемняющий псевдоэлемент поверх блока с картинкой в фоне, не забудьте расположить контент сверху псевдоэлемента.

```css
.bg {
  background: url(http://placeimg.com/500/300/any);
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.bg:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  left:0; top:0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.bg__content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class=bg>
  <div class=bg__content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repellendus sunt facilis incidunt laudantium perferendis numquam assumenda, blanditiis deserunt quisquam velit sit dolorem explicabo, nihil libero, voluptatibus nulla ullam! Aliquam, provident.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: О, а я уже похожее запостил :)

Comment: именно, но я раньше )

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать псевдоэлемент с отрицательным `z-index`:

```css
html, body, div {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.6);
  font-size: 6em;
  color: white;
}

div::before {
  content: "";
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgLtG.jpg);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div>Just a text</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо снова но предыдущий ответ был намного легче

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan, согласен. Но у этого должна бы поддержка браузерами быть побольше - те, которые множественные фоны не умели: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds vs http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gencontent (IE8 и Opera 10-).

Comment: @ArmanGhazaryan, я неправильно поддержку того способа оценил - градиенты тоже не везде есть: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-gradients. Получается, у этого ещё IE9. А IE8 в обоих лесом из-за http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-colors

Answer (score 0):

Сделай полупрозрачную картинку и сохрани в png.

Формат jpg не поддерживает прозрачность.

Comment: Это совет-вредитель — фоновую картинку на весь экран сохранять в пнг :)

Comment: щяс попробую спасибо

Comment: @SashaOmelchenko, ну не в gif же?)))